# How to estimate a Spark DataFrame's row count after join two or more table?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, execution, sql-execution-plan, explain

I'm developing a feature, support dynamic sql as input, and then using the input to  submit a spark job. But the inputs are unpredicatable, some inputs may exceed the limit, it's a dager for me. I want to check the sql's cost before submit the job, is a way I can estimate the cost accurately?

My Spark conf is  :

```
Spark Version: 3.3.1
conf:  
  spark.sql.cbo.enabled: true
  spark.sql.statistics.histogram.enabled:true
```

example:
I have a dataFrame `df1` like this

```
n   x   y   z
'A' 1   2   3
'A' 4   5   6
'A' 7   8   9
'A' 10  11  12
'A' 13  14  15
'A' 16  17  18
'A' 19  20  21
'A' 22  23  24
'A' 25  26  27
'A' 28  29  30
```

row count of `df1.join(df1,"n","left").join(df1,"n","left")` should be  1000

row count of `df1.join(df1,"n","left").join(df1,"n","left")` should be 10

but result of `dataFrame.queryExecution.optimizedPlan.stats` is awlyways 1000 for examples above.

I've tried in some way:

1. `dataFrame.queryExecution.optimizedPlan.stats`, but the es rows is much bigger than actual rows, especially when `join` operation exists.
2. Use `dataFrame.rdd.countApprox`. The problem is that it need much time to get the actual result when dataFrame is big
3. I also try to use `org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CommandUtils#calculateMultipleLocationSizesInParallel`, it's better than `dataFrame.rdd.countApprox`, but in some extreme scenario, it also cost more than tens of minutes。

Comment: what the type of join you use "left", "inner" ... can you also provide a code of your joins please?

Comment: join type is "left", example has added

Answer (score 0):

**First let's calculate the number of rows in each table**

```
df1_count = df1.count()
df2_count = df2.count()
df3_count = df3.count()
```

**Then use cogroup to create a DataFrame containing the row counts from each table**

```
counts_df = df1.cogroup(df2, df3)
```

**Add up the row counts to get the estimated total number of rows in the joined DataFrame**

```
estimated_row_count = counts_df.sum()
```

**Eventually, when you join, you can try this approach**

```
joined_df = df1.join(df2, on=..., how=...).join(df3, on=..., how=...)

exact_row_count = joined_df.count()
```

Comment: I am using spark 3.3.1 in `scala` language. I didn't find function `cogroup` in `org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset`, and only find it in `org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions`.     And I can use `df1.rdd.zipWithIndex().cogroup(df2.rdd.zipWithIndex())`  to do similar thing, the result is a `RDD[(Row, (Iterable[Long], Iterable[Long]))]`, but no `sum` function exists. I can use `counts_df.map(x=>x._2._1.size * x._2._2.size).reduce(_+_)` to  get the sum. I'm not sure whether my understanding is correct. Would you please confirm it for me